# Accidental Unix Mac Terminal Commands

Tags: macos, terminal, unix

I accidentally used the following commands in terminal:

1. In recovery mode: `nvram boots-args="x"`
2. In a user profile in terminal: 
   (a) `sudo nvram boots-agr=""` and 
   (b) `sudo nvram boots-args=""`, 
   and then typed in the sudo password.

Will this affect the system at all, since these are misspelled commands? Usually the command is: `nvram boot-args=""`, which has no "s" in boot, and "agr" is not used, but instead "args" is used.

Also, will it matter that a wrong command was used using the "sudo" command first?

Answer (score 2):

The superfluous variable should *in theory* not have any adverse effects, unless the startup code has some very specific bugs/flaws (which I do not assume). But these extra definitions will continue to **take up space** in an area with somewhat limited capacity, and **affect clarity**.

You can use `nvram -p` to dump and inspect all variables.

With a `nvram -d boots-agr` you can get rid of the ill-named one, here: *boots.agr*. This will most probably require `sudo`.

As always, `man nvram` is your friend. And when using `sudo`, be very *very* alert; you can do things which cannot be easily revoked - an accidental `-c` to `nvram` for example would have a very nasty effect. As a consequence, you should double-check all parameters given here.

Comment: Thanks @jvb. How would I specifically delete the Audi boots-arg in terminal on a MacBook Pro? Is it the same...sudo nvram -d boots-arg? Do I leave out the “x” and “”? Also, man nvram does exactly what? I want to essentially undo anything I inadvertently did. I was trying to boot up in safe mode but accidentally typed in the various typos sudo nvram boots-agr=“” in the user profile and nvram boots-arg=“-x” in recovery mode.

Comment: `man nvram` will display the *man(ual) page* for the nvram tool, and explain the arguments and their usage. There you will find an example for setting and removing a variable... in case of `-d`, you just give the *name* (not *name="value"*). I really can recommend using `man`, it works for most commands you find on a system.

Comment: thanks. Will it inform me if I have to use sudo with nvram-d, or should I just use it anyway? Or is this best done from recovery mode?

Comment: Use `sudo` sparingly - its main function is to *act as a safeguard*. When a command fails due to "insufficient permissions", check if you really mean to do that. Make sure you understand *exactly* what you are attempting to do. Double-check each parameter, *then* use `sudo`. Same goes for recovery mode, but even *more* decidedly. - I'm now feeling somewhat queasy talking about `sudo` and `nvram` while you did not know about `man`... feels a bit like a phone support hotline for chainsaw juggling... remember *you* are at the end with the chainsaws. You are accountable to make informed decisions.

Comment: Thank you @jbv :) When I did a nvram -p I did not see the boots-agr or boots-arg variables. Should I still remove them with the nvram -d command? I'm assuming that the MacBook Pro OS prevented me from creating any nvram variables as a default saving feature...or the nvram -p doesn't show the created variables?